# What does "brokenness" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brokenness

"Reynolds says he hopes that his books can serve as both a mirror of a life and a window into another. “All I want kids to know is that I see them for who they are and not who everyone thinks they are,” he says. He is committed, he says, to getting their stories right — “and putting that on the page with integrity and balance, to acknowledge the glory and the brokenness. That’s all I want to do. It’s a lot, but so are they.”"

Source: https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/books/he-didnt-read-books-as-a-kid-but-jason-reynolds-wants-to-make-sure-your-kids-do/2017/10/23/ed4b55da-9d4c-11e7-9083-fbfddf6804c2_story.html?hpid=hp_hp-cards_hp-card-arts%3Ahomepage%2Fcard&utm_term=.666fb76b3c25

Comment: *Brokenness* literally means "the state or condition of being broken", like any *adjective*-ness combination does.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the word 'brokenness', the author wants to convey the meaning of *imperfection*. He wants to say that he will be completely disinterested and unbiased in his judgements. He will acknowledge the glory of those stories as well as their imperfection.